# MongoDB in OpenVZ (zone_reclaim_mode)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, vps, openvz

First of all, I do apologize for not being able to find the answer on my own. I tried searching hard, but found pretty much nothing.

When I start 'mongo' shell on my Ubuntu VPS, it tells me the following:

```
2014-12-17T19:48:02.624+0000 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ which can cause issues on versions of RHEL older than RHEL6.
2014-12-17T19:48:02.624+0000 [initandlisten]
2014-12-17T19:48:02.624+0000 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode is 1
2014-12-17T19:48:02.624+0000 [initandlisten] **          We suggest setting it to 0
2014-12-17T19:48:02.624+0000 [initandlisten] **          http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt
```

I can not change the value in /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode as it is telling me it can not be opened for writing. Of course, I stop the mongod service first.

So I'm kind of lost about where to search for a solution, as I'm a newbie to Linux. Does anybody know the answer or is able to point me to a right direction?

Comment: StackOverflow focuses on programming-related questions (see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)); the [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) StackExchange site would be more appropriate for Linux admin questions. The kernel.org link in the log warning is a pointer to the Linux documentation. There is also an answer on ServerFault showing usage: [assigning write permissions to /proc/sys/vm in ubuntu](http://serverfault.com/questions/535328/assigning-write-permissions-to-proc-sys-vm-in-ubuntu). Note: you need to run sysctl with `sudo` or as the root user.

Comment: Stennie,
Thank you so much!
I do apologize for hitting the wrong site. Was in a hurry for solution.
Thanks ;)